# Spatialite return XY coordinate in Double Precision

Tags: qgis, qspatialite

I'm trying to return the first vertex of a polyline in QspatiaLite. The spatial function `x()` is used, but it returns an integer coordinate value. How can I return the coordinate value as double precision? This is my query:

```
SELECT id, AsText(StartPoint(Geometry)), X(PointN(Geometry, 1))
FROM shp_lane
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Would you mind pasting code into code block, and changing image to just show results pane?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in QSpatialite. I ran the same code against a local data file, and observed the same behavior. I recommend using QGIS DB Manager instead, which returns the desired floating point result, as shown here:

[image]